# Fantasy book about a girl whose use of both men's and women's magic makes her an outcast

Tags: story-identification, novel, magic, powers

Men do one kind of magic, women do another. The magic for one is sky based, the other is earth based. The main character (a girl) ends up breaking down the barrier to show that blending the types of magic makes the spells stronger.

The cover of the book was a reddish and gold based color. It showed the main character and a sort of doorway or archway with a man and maybe a second female character.

The person I'm asking for doesn't think it was a young adult novel. It was a run of the mill fantasy book and she thinks the author was a woman. It was published in the 1960s or 1970s.

She said the book is not Terry Pratchett’s “*Equal Rites*”.

Comment: If you go https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/story-identification/info, you'll find a list of questions. Answering those (and putting the answers in your question) will help ferret out additional details you might remember that will help us help you. As it is, I think we may have answered this one before. I'm researching.

Comment: This is a common trope in fantasy writing -- TV Tropes has several related tropes, including [Gender Restricted Ability](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/GenderRestrictedAbility) and [Unequal Rites](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/UnequalRites). As FuzzyBoots has said, you'll need to narrow it down more for us to identify a specific book.

Comment: Renee, you can merge your accounts by following the directions that start [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts).

Comment: Renee, if you're going to edit the answer, you need to do so from the same account, otherwise it looks like a random user (who happens to share the same username as you) is doing the edits.

Comment: I was thinking this was Barbara Hambly's *Sisters of the Raven* but as far as I know, it never had a cover like the one described.  Colors are right, the but only image was a small medallion of a flying raven.  It's also 15-20 years too new.